# Add new row in ag-grid for server-side mode

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ag-grid

I use server-side data mode for my ag-grid project. However one feature involves adding rows at the front end and allow users to fill the row with anything they want, note that I dont want to directly affect my DataBase( thus methods in https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-server-side-model-crud/ does not really work for me ) and after addition of rows I will allow users to click save button that trigger an Api to save these addition. For client side data this is very easy:

`this.rowData.push({col1: '', col2: ''})`
But for server side data mode this most certainly does not work as there does not exist a 'rowData' for me to push anything.
I understand that if I restrict a pagination size for my ag-grid, it seems illogical to add row no the grid, but still any workaround is highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this ? I happen to have a similar requirement in one of my modules.